# hide/unhide textfield by clicking bar button item in navigation

Tags: ios, tableview

I have one viewcontroller. At top i am having one textfield.And also i am having one bar button item(add button) at navigation bar. In `viewdidload` initially my texfield will be hidden. when user press that bar button (add button) my textfield should be visible. now its working well.

**Needer:**
 when user pressed (first time) my bar button (add button) should visible. then again when user press that same bar button item (add button) its should be again hidden.i did in visible .but i don't know  again how to make its hidden...i am very beginner please help me out

i know that its should be done in if statement.but i don't know what condition should use ...help me this

Thanks in advance !

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize textField;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    txtField.hidden = YES;

}
- (void)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    txtField.hidden = NO;


}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for that you have to define a Bool variable, change the status of that Boolean variable on the click of your button like this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    Bool isShowingTF;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize textField;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    isShowingTF = NO;
    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    txtField.hidden = YES;

}
- (void)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    if (isShowingTF) {
        txtField.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        txtField.hidden = NO;
    }
    isShowingTF = ! isShowingTF;
}


@end
```

Comment: one more question...while the textfield hide or vissible , is there any animation to show up while textfield is visible....

Comment: Yup you can apply animation to your textfield like animating the frame of textfield, or apply fade in fade out animation.

Comment: yes . but i need that animation when it in visible and hidden

Comment: I am not getting you properly, please will you explain in detail what you want to do.

Comment: the above code will hide and unhide when the button is pressed right !. At the same time when the text field is going to hide (when user press first time) its should go off with animation (like fade up, bounce up) .then when user press second time its should be visible .while its visible its should come down with some animation like i above said....

Comment: Yes you can do that, as I said in previous comment. Check animateWithDuration to fade in fade out your text field.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in many ways just like set `BOOL` for yes:No condition, else identify with `Tags` else use some common `NSString` like

```
@interface ViewController () {

UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
NSString *GettouchStr;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
txtField.hidden = YES;

 GettouchStr=@"hidden";

}

- (void)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
 if ([GettouchStr isEqualToString:@"hidden"])
 {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    txtField.alpha = 1;
} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {

  txtField.hidden = NO;
   GettouchStr=@"UNhidden";
 }];


  }
  else
   {

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    txtField.alpha = 0;
  } completion: ^(BOOL finished) { 
        txtField.hidden = YES;
        GettouchStr=@"hidden";

 }];


  }


 }
```

*Choice - 2* for additional animation

```
- (void)addButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
 if ([GettouchStr isEqualToString:@"hidden"])
 {

  txtField.alpha = 1;
      [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
   txtField.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
       txtField.alpha = 1;
       txtField.hidden = NO;
        GettouchStr=@"UNhidden";
    } completion:nil];
}];





  }
  else
   {
      txtField.alpha = 0;
      [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
   txtField.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
       txtField.alpha = 0;
       txtField.hidden = YES;
        GettouchStr=@"hidden";
    } completion:nil];
}];






  }


 }
```

*Choice-3*

see this [link](http://www.developerfeed.com/ios-fade-and-fade-out-view-effects/) may be help with you

Comment: one more question...while the textfield hide or vissible , is there any animation to show up while textfield is visible....

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    button.alpha = 1;
} completion: ^(BOOL finished)  i am getting error at button.alpha

Comment: which button that one??

Comment: @spikesa -- check the updated answer **button** in the place replace **txtField**

Comment: yes i got it thanks.. is there to do fade in fade out with this

Comment: @spikesa -- you want fade in fadeout animation ,I already did like Fade in fadeout , would you need some additional

Comment: great ..thanks alot ...its working.thanks for your help

Comment: @spikesa -- welcome my friend, in iOS we can do anything , have a Great day

Comment: can u give your skype or mail id.  i am having some doubt can  u clear it off. i am well begineer in ios

Comment: sure my friend my id karthik.saral@gmail.com(Facebook,Twitter, Skype, Gmail, stack overflow,instagram), whatsapp (+91-9790811202)

Comment: thanku so much..your skype id is not visible for me .please send request to @sathish chinniah

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4, If you have only one bar button item in the right side you can use this one,

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; //To Hide
>
> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem //To show

Suppose if you have multiple bar button in the right side, for example suppose you have two bar button items(search button and filter button) in the right side of your navigation item. And now you have to hide only search button, you can use like,

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [filterItem]

Now what happening is, you can completely hide the search button from the navigation item and the filter item comes in the place of search item

Then if you want to show the hided bar button,

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchItem, filterItem]

Now in the navigationItem searchItem comes as the first item, filterItem comes as the second item.